# How does x86 pause instruction work in spinlock *and* can it be used in other scenarios?

Tags: multithreading, x86, cpu-architecture, instructions, spinlock

The `pause` instruction is commonly used in the loop of testing [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), when some other thread owns the spinlock, to mitigate the tight loop. It's said that it is equivalent to some NOP instructions. Could somebody tell me how exactly it works for spinlock optimization? It seems to me that even the NOP instructions are a waste of CPU time. Will they decrease CPU usage?

Another question is that could I use pause instruction for other similar purposes. For example, I have a busy thread which keeps scanning some places (e.g. a queue) to retrieve new nodes; however, sometimes the queue is empty and the thread is just wasting cpu time. Sleep the thread and wake it up by other threads may be an option, however the thread is critical, so I don't want to make it sleep.

Could pause instruction work for my purpose to mitigate the CPU usage? Currently it uses 100% cpu of a physical core?

Comment: The point of a spin-wait *is* to waste CPU time.  Burning 100% core is *bad* for perf, it prevents another thread from giving your worker something to do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[PAUSE](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PAUSE.html) notifies the CPU that this is a spinlock wait loop so memory and cache accesses may be optimized.  See also [pause instruction in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/pause-instruction-in-x86) for some more details about avoiding the memory-order mis-speculation when leaving the spin-loop.

PAUSE may actually stop CPU for some time to save power.  Older CPUs decode it as REP NOP, so you don't have to check if its supported.  Older CPUs will simply do nothing (NOP) as fast as possible.

See also https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops

---

Update: I don't think it's a good idea to use PAUSE in queue checking unless you are going to make your queue spinlock-like (and there is no obvious way to do it).

Spinning for a very long time is still very bad, even with PAUSE.

Comment: Yes, I have this impression that PAUSE is a specialized instruction, thus not appropriate for other purposes, maybe due to its side effects. I'm interested in the details. Maybe the intel manual is a good reference:)

Comment: BTW, PAUSE will not solve your problem: it will halt CPU to save power but will not reschedule it for other tasks. Hanging inside PAUSE or doing busyloop makes no difference, you will still get 100% CPU load, just with lower power consumption.

Comment: Both of your links are dead now. I suggest https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops

Comment: @ZanLynx: dead now as well. At least related in this article: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/a-common-construct-to-avoid-the-contention-of-threads-architecture-agnostic-spin-wait-loops.html

Answer (score 21):

A processor suffers a severe performance penalty when exiting
the loop because it detects a possible memory order violation. The PAUSE instruction
provides a hint to the processor that the code sequence is a spin-wait loop. The
processor uses this hint to avoid the memory order violation in most situations,
which greatly improves processor performance. For this reason, it is recommended
that a PAUSE instruction be placed in all spin-wait loops.
An additional function of the PAUSE instruction is to reduce the power consumed by Intel processors.

[source: Intel manual]

Answer (score 8):

## Pause-based spin-wait loops

As I understood from your questions, the waits in your case are known in advance to be very long. In this case, spin-wait loops are not recommended at all. But if you are using a spin-loop that keeps checking a value from memory (e.g. a byte-sized synchronization variable), use `PAUSE`. See the Section 11.4.2 "Synchronization for Short Periods" of the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-optimization-reference-manual.html).

You wrote that you have a "thread which keeps scanning some places (e.g. a queue) to retrieve new nodes".

In such a case (i.e. the long wait), Intel recommends using synchronization API functions of your operating system. For example, you can create an event when a new node appears in a queue, and just wait for this event using the `WaitForSingleObject(Handle, INFINITE)`. The queue will trigger this event whenever a new node will appear.

According to the Intel Optimization Reference Manual, Section, 2.3.4 "Pause Latency in Skylake Client Microarchitecture",

> The PAUSE instruction is typically used with software threads
> executing on two logical processors located in the same processor
> core, waiting for a lock to be released. Such short wait loops tend to
> last between tens and a few hundreds of cycles, so performance-wise it
> is better to wait while occupying the CPU than yielding to the OS.

By "tens and a few hundreds of cycles" of the above quote I understand from 20 to 500 CPU cycles.

500 CPU cycles on a 4500 MHz Intel Core i7 7700K processor (released on January 2017, based on Kaby-Lake-S microarchitecture) is 0.0000001 seconds, i.e. 1/10000000th of a second: the CPU can make 10 million times per second this 500-CPU-cycles loop.

This 500 cycle limit recommended by Intel is theoretical, and all depends on particular use case, i.e. on the logic of the code that needs to be synchronized by spin-wait loops. Some scenarios like [FastMM4-AVX memory manger for Delphi](https://github.com/maximmasiutin/FastMM4-AVX) work better with the value of 5000, according to the benchmarks. Even though, these benchmarks do not always reflect real-world scenario, and real program use cases should be measured.

As you see, this `PAUSE`-based spin-wait loop is for really *short* periods of time.

On the other hand, each call to an API function like Sleep() experiences the expensive cost of a context switch, which can be 10000+ cycles; it also suffers the cost of ring 3 to ring 0 transitions, which can be 1000+ cycles.

If there are more threads then the processor cores (multiplied to hyperthreading feature, if present) are available, and a thread will get switched to another one in the middle of a critical section, waiting for the critical section from another thread may really take *looong*, at least 10000+ cycles, so the `PAUSE`-based spin-wait loop will be futile.

In addition to the relevant chapters of the Intel Optimization Reference Manual, please see the following articles for more information:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/long-duration-spin-wait-loops-on-hyper-threading-technology-enabled-intel-processors
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops

When the wait loop is expected to last for thousands of cycles or more, it is
preferable to yield to the operating system by calling one of the OS synchronization API functions, such as `WaitForSingleObject` or `SwitchToThread` on Windows OS.

As a conclusion: in your scenario, the `PAUSE`-based spin-wait loop won't be the best choice, since your waiting time is long while the spin-wait loop is intended for very short loops.

The `PAUSE` instruction takes about 140 CPU cycles on processors based on Skylake microarchitecture, or later processors. For example, it is just or 35.10ns on Intel Core i7-6700K CPU (4GHz) released on August 2015, or 49.47ns on Intel Core i7-1165G7 CPU for mobile devices released on September 2020. On earlier processors (prior to Skylake), like those based on Haswell microarchitecture, it has about 9 cycles. It is 2.81ns on Intel Core i5-4430 (3GHz) released on June 2013. So, for the long loops, it's better to relinquish control to other threads using the OS synchronization API functions than to occupy CPU with the `PAUSE` loop, regardless of the microarchitecture.

## Test, Test-and-Set

Please note that the spin-wait loops have also to be implemented properly. Intel recommends the so-called "test, test-and-set" technique (see Section 11.4.3 "Optimization with Spin-Locks" of the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual) to determine the availability of the synchronization variable. According to this technique, the first "test" is done via the normal (non-locking) memory load to prevent excessive bus locking during the spin-wait loop; if the variable is available upon the non-locking memory load of the first step ("test"), proceed to the second step ("test-and-set") which is done via the bus-locking atomic `xchg` instruction.

But be aware that this two-steps approach of using "test" before "test-and-set" can increase the cost for the un-contended case comparing to just single-step "test-and-set". The initial read-only access might only get the cache line in Shared state, so the atomic operation like test-and-set (`xchg`) or compare-and-swap (`cmpxchg`) still needs a ''Read For Ownership'' (RFO) operation to get exclusive ownership of the cache line. [This operation is issued by a processor trying to write into a cache line that is in the Shared state.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)

- [Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure? If not, is it better than xchg for spinlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008857/does-cmpxchg-write-destination-cache-line-on-failure-if-not-is-it-better-than)
- [atomic operation cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538070/atomic-operation-cost)

Comment: This would be a lot better if you said "a spin-loop will be bad, since your waiting time is long".  Saying "`pause` won't help" is wrong: if you design your program badly and spin for a really long time, it still helps to `pause` inside those loops.  In fact, it's even *more* important in that case.  (But still obviously the wrong choice for synchronization.  Much better to use an OS-supported spinlock that can yield the CPU and wait for a wake-up if it doesn't get the lock quickly.  http://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex/.

Comment: Also, `pause` helps even without hyperthreading:  it avoids a memory-order mis-speculation stall on the load when the leaving the spin-loop.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/pause-instruction-in-x86

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I will re-word the answer, I mean that `EnterCriticalSection` is better than long loop with a `pause`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you again for your valuable suggestions and edits. By the way the link to a lightweight mutex described in https://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex/ that uses CriticalSection only gives advantages for un-contended cases (single thread) like in the example of that article. In highly contented cases, EnterCritical section, after just one locked "test-and-set" will proceed to expensive context switching (10000+) while PAUSE-based spin-wait loop may get lock at less cost after a few iterations, and cycles took by 'pause' are not wasted but surrendered.

Comment: No, PAUSE doesn't consume such a lot of cycles - check the latency- / throughput-tables on agner.org.

Comment: @BonitaMontero could you please clarify: what exactly do you mean by "such a lot of cycles"?

Answer (score 1):

The PAUSE instruction also appears to be used in hyper-threading processors to mitigate performance impact on other hyper threads, presumably by relinquishing more CPU time to them.

The following Intel article outlines this, and not surprisingly recommends avoiding busy wait loops on such processors:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/long-duration-spin-wait-loops-on-hyper-threading-technology-enabled-intel-processors