# Is the performance of 'parallelStream' function reduced by the atomic variables?

Tags: java, parallelstream

So let's say we have the following setup:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList( "lore ipsum ..", ... 10000 strings);
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
strings.parallelStream().forEach( myString -> {
   System.out.println(count.incrementAndGet());
   System.out.println(myString); 
   // ... do more computing
});
```

Will this code perform considerable faster if I don't use the atomic variable?
Is it a good practice to use atomic variables or better try to avoid them if you can?

Other links:
[Parallel stream - race conditions with atomic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55843518/race-condition-occurring-during-use-of-parallel-streams-and-atomic-variables?),
[Parallel processing](https://blog.oio.de/2016/01/22/parallel-stream-processing-in-java-8-performance-of-sequential-vs-parallel-stream-processing/)

Comment: The "not so important" part of the example is really bad in this case, the main time consuming operation will be `System.out.println` and `incrementAndGet` will be like nothing compared to that. If "your work" part actually takes some time, then I wouldn't really worry about `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: i dont think it will impact performance , as atomicinteger is non blocking. with the context of thread contention

Comment: Why not `parallelStream().count()`? Why count manually? i don't have the answer, but [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) is a class to reduce contention when incrementing a long value (i.e. counting)

Comment: @knittl because the main goal is not counting, that's just for debugging.

Comment: @Amongalen the `Sysout` is just for this example in the actual code will be a logger and the function will do something else.