# __atomic_test_and_set vs __atomic_compare_exchange_n

Tags: c, gcc, locking, atomic

I suppose I can use `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` in place of `__atomic_test_and_set`.

Is there any performance benefit of one over other for using these builtins for boolean values?

Any input other than number of arguments is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using the API provided by C11's `<stdatomic.h>`. The [`__atomic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) builtins are just how GCC implements them under the hood, using standard API makes your code more portable.

- `__atomic_test_and_set` is what GCC translates [`atomic_flag_test_and_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag_test_and_set) to.
- `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` is [`atomic_compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange).

gcc6 on AMD64 with `-O2` compiles

```
if (atomic_flag_test_and_set(&atomic_flag_var) == 0) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&atomic_var, &clear, 1)) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

to a `xchg` followed by a `test` in the first case. The other one expectedly to a `cmpxchg`. It's unlikely, that you'll experience any noticeable difference between the two. See this answer: [Relative performance of swap vs compare-and-swap locks on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339769/relative-performance-of-swap-vs-compare-and-swap-locks-on-x86).

So, which one to use? If you need an atomic flag, use [`atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag). The standard guarantees that this will be lock-free. No such guarantee exists for any of the other `_Atomic` types.