# Can you implement a timer without a "sleep" in it using standard c++/c++11 only?

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

Note: since this question is specifically about timers, its important to note there is a bug in gcc that if you are using std::condition_variable::wait_for (or wait_util) it uses the system clock even if you pass it a std::chrono::steady_clock time point. This means the timer is not monotonic - i.e. if you change the system time forward by a day then your timer may not trigger for a day + your timeout - if you change the time backwards your timer may trigger immediately.

See: [condition_variable workaround for wait_until with system time change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631963/condition-variable-workaround-for-wait-until-with-system-time-change)

The fix for this bug went into gcc v10+

**END**

I have the following code (hand-copied in):

```
// Simple stop watch class basically takes "now" as the start time and 
// returns the diff when asked for.
class stop_watch {...}

// global var
std::thread timer_thread;

void start_timer(int timeout_ms)
{
    timer_thread = std::thread([timeout_ms, this](){
        stop_watch sw;
        while (sw.get_elapsed_time() < timeout_ms)
        {
            // Here is the sleep to stop from hammering a CPU
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }

        // Do timeout things here...
        std::cout << "timed out!" << std::endl;
    })
}
```

I did not want to get too bogged down in the detail of the class I writing so this is a very cut-down version. The full class calls a function call-back and has a variable to cancel the timer etc...

I just wanted to focus on the "sleep" part. Can I implement something like this without a sleep or is there a better way to do it? - or is sleep perfectly good? - I was of the opinion that sleeps are generally a sign of bad design (I have read that a few places)... but I can't think of a way to implement a timer without one :(

**Additional Note:** The timer should have the requirement to be able to be stopped/woken at any time. Just adding that for clarity because it appears to affect what kind of solution to go for. In my original code (not this snippet) I used an atomic bool flag that can break out of the loop.

Comment: You probably have a design issue and want to use a [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) instead.  It has methods [`wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) and [`wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until).

Comment: How accurate does the timer need to be? Nothing wrong with using `sleep_for` in this way.

Comment: sleep is bad for *"synchronize"* multiple thread together, your usage might be fine.

Comment: in "standard c++11" this is about all you have. If you widen your net to include posix then you can build an io loop based on pselect et al. 
boost.asio is built (sort of) this way.

Comment: @HenriMenke I like the idea of wait_until(...), but I am thinking that if you wanted to exit the wait_until(...) part early I am not sure how you would do that?

Comment: @Bathsheba - well, for me its not real time so the best my OS can do is generally about 10-15ms, so around about that :) ... it does work really well, but I have recently been trying to remove all the hard-coded sleeps from our code - and generally its been making the code better  and more reliable/robust

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, I really really want to keep it strictly c++ only so that it is portable etc...

Comment: @code_fodder I completely understand. Unfortunately for anything other than the most trivial programs, the 'standard' is boost. The c++ standard is a little anaemic when it comes to functionality.

Comment: I think if you need a responsive exit from a timer function then using a sleep function is perfectly fine. Wrap it all up in a "timer" class and then you can forget about the details when you want to use it next.

Comment: If you sleep in some other way it's still a sleep. If some other way was better then the sleep function would use that some other way in the first place.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

C++11 provides us with `std::condition_variable`. In your timer you can wait until your condition has been met:

```
// Somewhere else, e.g. in a header:
std::mutex mutex;
bool condition_to_be_met{false};
std::condition_variable cv;

// In your timer:
// ...
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
if(!cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds{timeout_ms}, [this]{return condition_to_be_met;}))
std::cout << "timed out!" << std::endl;
```

You can find more information here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

To signal that the condition has been met do this in another thread:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex}; // Same instance as above!
    condition_to_be_met = true;
}
cv.notify_one();
```

Comment: just a tiny comment. Adjustment of `condition_to_be_met` is always guarded by a mutex, so it does not need to be atomic. Also, almost always release the lock before calling `notify_one()`. see docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one

Comment: That is so cool! - I have used condition_variable quite a lot, but I just never really looked into wait_for() ... it does all the work for me!...nice : ))  thanks

Comment: `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};` outside of `wait_for`? This means that `wait_for` will always work same way as `sleep`, since `condition_to_be_met` can't be modified until `wait_for` is completed. So `condition_to_be_met` should be atomic, but no extra mutex should be used!

Comment: @MarekR That's not true, please read the reference on `std::condition_variable` and `std::unique_lock`. Basically, `wait_for` locks and unlocks the mutex whenever it needs to. That's why `wait_for` needs a `std::unique_lock` to work and cannot take a `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: @RichardHodges OT… unfortunately, though, `helgrind` will produce a warning (i.e. false positive) if the mutex is not held during the notification, because it is ignorant of the actual waiting condition and cannot then prove that proper synchronization was performed. A possible solution (other than suppressions) is to introduce a build variable `HELGRIND` and then use `#ifdef HELGRIND` to see whether the mutex should be held during the notification.

Comment: @ArneVogel I checked the HELGRIND documentation. They argue that you should hold the lock while notifying. This is wrong. Best thing to do is file a bug report and direct them to c++ docs, or (if possible?) turn off HELGRIND around condition_variable notifications.

Comment: @RichardHodges "They argue that you should hold the lock while notifying." – Are you referring to "The canonical POSIX-recommended usage scheme for condition variables […]"? They don't discuss this particular issue, but the problem is likely not ignorance but the difficulty of fixing the check without introducing false negatives, consider for an `atomic<bool> b`, `mutex m`, `condition_variable c`, correct: `b=true;lock_guard<mutex>{m};c.notify_one();` and incorrect: `lock_guard<mutex>{m};b=true;c.notify_one();` – deciding this case requires semantical knowledge of `b`, and likely AI.

Answer (score 8):

While your code will "work", it is sub-optimal for the intended purpose as timer.

There exists `std::this_thread::sleep_until` which, depending on the implementation, *possibly* only just calls `sleep_for` after doing some math anyway, but which *might* use a proper timer, which is vastly superior in terms of precision and reliability.

Generally, sleeping is not the best, most reliable, and most accurate thing to do, but sometimes, if just waiting for some approximate time is what's intended, it can be "good enough".

In any case, repeatedly sleeping for small amounts as in your example is a bad idea. This will burn a lot of CPU on needlessly rescheduling and waking threads, and on some systems (Windows in particular, though Windows 10 isn't so bad in that respect any more) it may add a considerable amount of jitter and uncertainity. Note that different Windows versions round to the scheduler's granularity *differently*, so in addition to generally being not overly precise, you do not even have consistent behavior. Rounding is pretty much "who cares" for a single large wait, but it is a serious problem for a series of small waits.

Unless the ability to abort the timer prematurely is a necessity (but in that case, there are better ways of implementing that, too!), you should sleep *exactly once*, never more, for the full duration. For correctness you should then check that you indeed got the time you expected because some systems (POSIX, notably) may under-sleep.

Over-sleeping is a different problem if you need it *right*, because even if you check and detect that case correctly, once it has happened there's nothing you can do about it (time has already passed, and never comes back). But alas, that's just a fundamental weakness of sleeping, not much you can do. Luckily, most people can shrug this problem off, most of the time.

Comment: Ah, yes... that is exactly why I am doing multiple sleeps, incase the caller wants to stop the timer (in which case I was using an atomic bool variable within the loop - if it gets set to true is escapes the loop...). But as you say, sleeping many times is not so "clever", so I like the `cond_var.wait_for(...)` idea, that seems to capture both cases. :)

Comment: The "correct" way (or _one_ correct way) of doing this would be to check an atomic flag prior to executing the to-do stuff once the timer fires, basically that's very much like using the `scope_guard` idiom and calling `disarm()` if you want to cancel the timer (only just, normal implementations of `scope_guard` aren't threadsafe, they need not be). You only need to check once at the very end. Yes, if you cancel, you will effectively have a superfluous thread doing nothing, until it exits. Get over it. You don't spawn and cancel 5,000 times per program invocation, so who cares.

Comment: mmm... I do see what you are saying. But it feels wrong to leave "active" timers kicking around just because you can't implement a decent way of ending them :o  ... or is that just my OCD?!

Comment: Well a thread that is sleeping does nothing. Once it wakes up, it checks one boolean, sees that it should exit, and exits. All you really lose is the address space reserved for the thread's stack. Unless you have **a lot** of threads, this doesn't matter. The next best thing would be to simply kill the threads. While they're sleeping, this is 100% harmless. Only problem is a) C++ doesn't support it, so you need to go low level, and b) what happens if you kill them while they're half through the critical section after waking up! Problem b) can be addressed cleanly under POSIX, but not Windows.

Comment: yeah I did have a look at how to kill off threads - the only way I found was std::terminate (or is it std::thread::terminate), but that also terminates the entire application :o. So on more consideration I think your answer is a valid one... +1, but not the one I prefer because I like being neat :o ... even if its just in my head only!

Answer (score 4):

You *could* busy-wait checking the time in a loop, until it reaches the time you're waiting for.  That's obviously horrible, so don't do it.  Sleeping for 10ms is somewhat better, but definitely poor design.  ([@Damon's answer has some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817018/can-you-implement-a-timer-without-a-sleep-in-it-using-standard-c-c11-only/51824421#51824421).)

---

**There's nothing wrong with using functions with `sleep` in their name if that's the most useful thing for your program to do right then.**

The suggestion to avoid `sleep` is probably recommending against the general pattern of sleeping for a short time, checking if there's anything to do, then sleeping again.  Instead, block waiting for an event with no timeout, or a very long timeout.  (e.g. a GUI should wait for a keypress / click by calling a blocking function, with a timeout set to wake it up when it's time to autosave or whatever future thing is coming up next.  You normally don't need a separate thread *just* to sleep, but you might if there's nowhere sensible to insert checks for the current time.)

**Letting the OS wake you up when it's finally time to do anything is *much* better.  This avoids context switches and cache pollution slowing down other programs and wasting power while you're spinning on short sleeps.**

If you know there's nothing to do for some time, just sleep for that long with a single sleep.  AFAIK, multiple short sleeps won't improve the accuracy of the wake-up time on mainstream OSes like Windows, Linux, or OS X.  You might avoid an instruction-cache miss if your code had been waking up frequently, but if that amount of delay is a real problem you probably need a real-time OS and a much more sophisticated approach to timing.  (Like wake up a fraction of a second early and spin-wait from there.)

If anything, a thread that's been sleeping for a long time is more likely to wake up exactly when it requested, while a thread that was running recently and slept for only 10ms might run into scheduler timeslice issues.  On Linux, threads that have been asleep for a while get a priority boost when they do wake up.

---

Using a function without `sleep` in the name that blocks for 1 second is no better than using `sleep` or `this_thread::sleep_for`.

(Apparently you want another thread to be able to wake you up.  This requirement is buried in the question, but yes a condition variable is a good portable way to do that.)

---

If you want to use pure ISO C++11, then [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) are your best bet. These are defined in standard header `<thread>`.

[`sleep(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) is a POSIX function (like `nanosleep`), not part of ISO C++11.  If that's not a problem for you, then feel free to use it if it's appropriate.

---

For portable high-precision OS-assisted sleep-for-an-interval, C++11 introduced
**[`std::this_thread::sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> &sleep_duration)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)**  (The cppreference page has a code example of using it.)

> Blocks the execution of the current thread for *at least* the specified sleep_duration.
>
> This function may block for longer than sleep_duration due to
> scheduling or resource contention delays.
>
> The standard recommends that a steady clock is used to measure the
> duration. If an implementation uses a system clock instead, the wait
> time may also be sensitive to clock adjustments.

---

To sleep *until* a clock reaches a specified time (possibly taking into account changes / corrections to the system time):

**[`std::this_thread::sleep_until(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>& sleep_time)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until)**

> Blocks the execution of the current thread until specified `sleep_time`
> has been reached.
>
> The clock tied to `sleep_time` is used, which means that adjustments of
> the clock are taken into account. Thus, the duration of the block
> might, but might not, be less or more than `sleep_time - Clock::now()`
> at the time of the call, depending on the direction of the adjustment.
> The function also may block for longer than until after `sleep_time` has
> been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

---

Notice that `sleep_for` is meant to be unaffected by changes to the system clock, so it sleeps for that much real time.

But `sleep_until` is supposed to let you wake up when the system clock reaches a given time, even if it did that by being adjusted (NTP or manual setting), if used with a clock other than `steady_clock`.

---

### Sleep gotchas: late / early wakeup

The caveats about possibly sleeping too long also apply to `sleep` and `nanosleep`, or any other OS-specific sleep or timeout (including the condition-variable approach in @Sebastian's answer), of course.  It's unavoidable; a realtime OS can give you upper bounds on that extra delay, though.

You're already doing something like this with your 10ms sleeps:

**Always assume that `sleep` or whatever other function woke up late, and check the current time instead of using dead-reckoning in any case where that matters.**

You *can't* build a reliable clock out of repeated `sleep`.
e.g. don't build a count-down timer that sleeps for 1 second, decrements and displays a counter, then sleeps for another second.  Unless it's just a toy and you don't care much about accuracy.

Some sleep functions such as POSIX `sleep(3)` can also wake up early on a signal.  If waking too early is a correctness problem, check the time and if necessary go back to sleep for the calculated interval.  (Or use `sleep_until`)

Comment: Peter - I might be being slow here... but I don't quite get what you are getting at. I think I am doing what you are suggesting already? I am using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(...)` already and my loop (buried in my stopwatch class) is taking a time time-stamp such that after each interval it checks the actual time taken (and not just a series of sleep_for()'s added together. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @code_fodder: I read the title and thought you were asking about `sleep`.  I only later realized you were already asking about `this_thread::sleep_for` but didn't have any good ideas for rewriting my answer.  The requirement that another thread be able to wake you was totally buried in your question, and not obvious from the code.  A conditional variable is a very good portable option there, otherwise do one sleep for the full duration.  Like Damon says, multiple short sleeps aren't efficient.  Not as bad as busy-waiting, but AFAIK short sleeps don't improve precision of the wake time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actaully I don't think I even added the requirement to wakeup... I probably should!.. good spot. But at least from your answer I can see that I started along the right direction : )

Comment: @isanae: I updated it to maybe make more sense as an answer to this question.  If you do just want to sleep, then avoiding functions with `sleep` in the name is not useful if you're just going to use some other function in a way that makes it block for a fixed interval.  @Damon's answer is better than mine, though.

Comment: I retracted my downvote 8 hours ago after your edit. I haven't upvoted it because I don't think this is a good quality answer: it's confused, it has many unrelated sections and it is unclear what or where the actual answer is. I would suggest trimming most of it and cleaning up the layout.

Comment: @isanae: ah, so it was someone else that recently switched their upvote to a downvote.  Thanks for the suggestions, I was going to just leave this alone but I think I've managed to usefully answer the "avoiding sleep" part of the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the updates Peter, useful information regarding the various sleep functionality. I don't quite see how it answers "avoiding sleep", looks like it more expands on the various uses of sleep (unless you mean that sleep_for and sleep_until are not "sleep"?). But anyway, I have learnt from that, so +1 : )

Comment: @code_fodder: Look at my 3rd paragraph: using a different function without "sleep" in the name isn't what they meant.  If you just want to block for an interval, use `sleep`, `sleep_for`, or `sleep_until`.  There's nothing wrong with the functions per-se, it's about a design that sleeps (especially for a short time) without other wakeup conditions probably being a poor design.  But if you're literally making a clock or stopwatch for humans to time things with, or to run a benchmark for a time, then yes you should just sleep with a function that has `sleep` in the name.