# What does __asm volatile ("pause" ::: "memory"); do?

Tags: c++, assembly, parallel-processing, x86, inline-assembly

I am looking at an open source C++ project which has the following code structure:

```
while(true) {
  // Do something work

  if(some_condition_becomes_true)
     break;

  __asm volatile ("pause" ::: "memory");
}
```

What does the last statement do? I understand that `__asm` means that it is an assembly instruction and I found some posts about `pause` instruction which say that the thread effectively hints the core to release resources and give other thread more resources (in context of hyper-threading). But what does `:::` do and what does `memory` do?

Comment: Inline assembler like that is very compiler-specific. You might want to read some documentation of the compiler to find out. From the syntax I assume it's the [GCC compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

Comment: It is the gcc  format for [extended assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). The `:` are just separators between (unused) optional arguments.

Comment: the "memory" part tells gcc that memory may have been modified inside the asm block. While it's not true (`pause` doesn't affect memory content), it's used as partial anti-reorder barrier for the compiler. Together with `volatile` keyword it's almost sure the `pause` will be at the end of the while-body and nothing from the code ahead will be moved after the `pause`, actually it may even prevent the optimizer to unroll the loop (or at least make it less likely). Which look as something what the author probably did want.

Comment: @Ped7g You should probably turn this into an answer...

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the pause is discussed in a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725676/how-does-x86-pause-instruction-work-in-spinlock-and-can-it-be-used-in-other-sc

Comment: @hlt I didn't want, because I don't fully understand extended inline assembly in gcc (and all the implications caused by that line in the source), I'm more like x86 assembly master, but I use `gcc` only as C and C++ compiler, the inline asm stuff is very tricky and most often pointless (using separate asm source file is often better), although in this particular case the usage looks reasonable. I still guessed there was some C/C++ way of achieving that, like `_mm_pause()` in the answer from Peter Cordes, but I don't know these. So in the end the better answer appeared. :)

Comment: @BoPersson The link in your comment shows `__asm__` being used, not `__asm`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `_mm_pause()` and a compile memory barrier wrapped into one GNU C Extended ASM statement.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

`asm("" ::: "memory")` prevents compile-time reordering of memory operations across it, like C++11 `std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.  (*not* `atomic_thread_fence`; although on x86 preventing compile-time reordering is sufficient to make it an acquire + release fence because the only run-time reordering that x86 allows is StoreLoad.)  See Jeff Preshing's [Memory Ordering at Compile Time](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) article.

Making the asm instruction part non-empty also means those asm instructions will run every time the C logically runs that source line (because it's `volatile`).

`pause` prevents speculative loads from causing memory-ordering mis-speculation pipeling clears (aka machine nukes).  It's useful inside spin loops that are waiting to see a value in memory.

**You might find this statement inside a spinloop written without C++11 std::atomic, to tell the compiler it has to re-read the value of a global variable**.  (Because the `"memory"` clobber means the compiler has to assume the asm statement might have modified the value of any globally-reachable memory.)

This looks like the context where you found it: `some_condition_becomes_true` probably includes reading a non-`atomic` / non-`volatile` global.

The C++11 equivalent of your loop:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <immintrin.h>
std::atomic<int> flag;

void wait_for_flag(void) {
    while(flag.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst == 0) {
        _mm_pause();
    }
}
```

(Not exactly equivalent, because your version has a full compiler barrier while mine only has a seq-cst load, so it's not a full signal-fence.  But *probably* what wasn't needed, and they just used something stronger than necessary to get the effect of volatile).

---

**Without the barrier or making `flag` atomic**, the compiler would have optimized it to:

```
// Do something work

if(some_condition_becomes_true) {
    // empty
} else {

  while(true) {
     // Do something work
     __asm volatile ("pause" ::: );  // no memory clobber
  }
}
```

i.e. **it would hoist the check on `some_condition_becomes_true` out of the loop and *not* re-read the global every time.**