# How to ensure that `methodB` is "blocked" if some threads are in `methodA` in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

`Class clazz` has two methods `methodA()` and `methodB()`.

> How to ensure that `methodB` is "blocked" if some threads are in `methodA` in Java (I am using Java 8)?

By "blocking methodB", I mean that "wait until no threads are in methodA()". (Thanks to @AndyTurner)

Note that the requirement above *allows* the following situations:

1. Multiple threads are simultaneously in `methodA`.
2. Multiple threads are in `methodB` while no threads are in `methodA`.
3. Threads in `methodB` does not prevent other threads from entering `methodA`.

---

My trial: I use `StampedLock lock = new StampedLock`.

- In `methodA`, call `long stamp = lock.readLock()`
- Create a new method `unlockB` and call `lock.unlockRead(stamp)` in it.
- In `methodB`, call `long stamp = lock.writeLock()` and `lock.unlockWrite(stamp)`.

However, this locking strategy disallows the second and the third situations above.

---

*Edit:* I realize that I have not clearly specified the requirements of the synchronization between `methodA` and `methodB`. The approach given by @JaroslawPawlak works for the current requirement (I accept it), but not for my original intention (maybe I should first clarify it and then post it in another thread).

Comment: Looks nasty because it contains data race between the threads that are still finishing work in methodB while new threads are entering methodA. Are you sure that's what you want and there is no way to distinguish some particular area which needs to be mutually exclusive in methodA and methodB while other parts could be executed concurrently?

Comment: condition 2, 3 conflicting each other. what happens when one thread gets into B when no one in A and suddenly some thread goes to A while the first thread still in B. ??

Comment: @bashnesnos That is what I want now. I want to achieve such a fine-grained synchronization because I am implementing a distributed application in which `methodA` and `methodB` involve remote calls and may result in a long delay. Thanks.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne The situation you describe is allowed. The only thing that is not allowed is that new threads call `methodB` while some threads are already in `methodA`.

Comment: Do `methodA()` or `methodB()` call themselves (or the other one) directly or indirectly?

Comment: @AndyTurner No.

Comment: What action should be taken if `methodB()` is called whilst other threads are in `methodA()`? Immediate return, block, exception etc?

Comment: @AndyTurner This is not allowed. By "no `methodB()` can be called while ...", I mean the call to `methodB()` should be blocked.

Comment: "Not allowed" implies an exception to me. By "block", do you mean "wait until no threads are in `methodA()`"?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes. I will update the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can do the trick:

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
private int threadsInA = 0;

public void methodA() {
    lock.lock();
    threadsInA++;
    semaphore.tryAcquire();
    lock.unlock();

    // your code

    lock.lock();
    threadsInA--;
    if (threadsInA == 0) {
        semaphore.release();
    }
    lock.unlock();
}

public void methodB() throws InterruptedException {
    semaphore.acquire();
    semaphore.release();

    // your code
}
```

Threads entering `methodA` increase the count and try to acquire a permit from semaphore (i.e. they take 1 permit if available, but if not available they just continue without a permit). When the last thread leaves `methodA`, the permit is returned. We cannot use `AtomicInteger` since changing the count and acquiring/releasing permit from semaphore must be atomic.

Threads entering `methodB` need to have a permit (and will wait for one if not available), but after they get it they return it immediately allowing others threads to enter `methodB`.

**EDIT:**

Another simpler version:

```
private final int MAX_THREADS = 1_000;
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_THREADS);

public void methodA() throws InterruptedException {
    semaphore.acquire();

    // your code

    semaphore.release();
}

public void methodB() throws InterruptedException {
    semaphore.acquire(MAX_THREADS);
    semaphore.release(MAX_THREADS);

    // your code
}
```

Every thread in `methodA` holds a single permit which is released when the thread leaves `methodA`.

Threads entering `methodB` wait until all 1000 permits are available (i.e. no threads in `methodA`), but don't hold them, which allows other threads to enter both methods while `methodB` is still being executed.

Comment: But why do you need a separate permit and a thread counter? Thread count is a permit itself (the threadInA == 0 condition).

Comment: Thanks. However, does this disallow the situation (the 2nd situation) where multiple threads can enter `methodB` (and execute the application code) given that no threads are in `methodA`? Is the trick that `semaphore.acquire()` is immediately followed by `semaphore.release()` for this situation?

Comment: @bashnesnos The semaphore is to have a waiting mechanism. `AtomicInteger` doesn't support waiting, while `Semaphore` on its own cannot do counting, unless we do something like 1k permits, thread in methodA acquires 1 permit and thread in methodB acquires all 1k permits.

Comment: @hengxin if no threads are in `A` then there is an available permit. Thread entering `B` takes this permit and releases it immediately, allowing other thread to enter `B`. As a result, you can have multiple threads in `B`. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Agreed, so you just use semaphore instead of using a condition object to signal waiting thread. I like that in your case threads entering methodB might still be stopped from doing stuff if a new threads enters methodA, rather than signal all the threads waiting. It might be a useful feature.

Comment: @bashnesnos was that for first or second solution? :) What do you think about the edit I just added?

Comment: That was for the first one :-) I don't like the second one, because it implies 2 * MAX_THREADS compareAndSwapInt operations for each thread in methodB.

Comment: @bashnesnos Could you please explain what you mean by compareAndSwapInt operations? I think second solution is much simpler, but I cannot really see any problem with it.

Comment: If you look into the `Semaphore.Sync.nonfairTryAcquireShared` and `Semaphore.Sync.tryReleaseShared` methods you will see them calling `compareAndSetState` (which calls `unsafe.compareAndSwapInt` in it's turn) in a loop which terminates when there are no permits left. So if you have 1000 permits acquire and release will cause 2000 compareAndSwapInt operations. IMO it's an overkill for such a synchronization. [CAS cost explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538070/atomic-operation-cost).

Comment: @bashnesnos I have just debugged the code for all 4 calls that are made to the semaphore and I cannot see any loop body executing more than once. Putting a breakpoint inside `compareAndSetState` and calling `methodA` once and `methodB` once results in exactly 4 hits.

Comment: You're right. I've missed that it does a CAS for (available - acquires) and not for each permit. Pretty dumb of me to suggest `java.util.concurrent` guys would do something like that, I should have looked twice. But still, my solution is slightly better because it does only 2 CAS operations per a thread in methodA, and yours - 2 CAS operations per thread in methodA and per thread in methodB :-)

Comment: @bashnesnos sounds a little bit like premature optimisation ;) We don't know what OP's code does, there might be other bigger bottlenecks than this ;) Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Yes, I have seen it (and your discussions with @bashnesnos). Thanks. I will try your code. And I will accept it if it works and no better ones appear in one day.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Consider this situation (w.r.t the second approach): Thread B enters methodB and executes the first two semaphore statements. Now Thread A enters methodA and executes `semaphore.acquire()` and the code. Before Thread A executing `semaphore.release()`, Thread B begins to execute the code in methodB. This is not what I want. But maybe I have not clearly specified the requirements of the synchronization between methodA and methodB.

Comment: @hengxin As long as there is at least one thread executing `methodA`, all threads entering `methodB` will wait at line `semaphore.acquire(MAX_THREADS);` until all threads leave `methodA`. Is that not what you want? Can you clarify what should happen when thread 1 attempts to enter `methodB` while thread 2 is still in `methodA`?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I realize that I have not clearly specified the requirements of the synchronization between methodA and methodB. Your approach works for the current requirement (I will accept it), but not for my original intention (maybe I should first clarify it and then post it in another thread). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an kind of external orchestrator?
I mean another class that will be responsible to call the methodA or methodB when it allowed.
Multi-thread can still be handle via locking or maybe just with some AtomicBoolean(s).

Please find below a naive draft of how to do it.

```
public class MyOrchestrator {

@Autowired
private ClassWithMethods classWithMethods;

private AtomicBoolean aBoolean = = new AtomicBoolean(true);

 public Object callTheDesiredMethodIfPossible(Method method, Object... params) {
   if(aBoolean.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
      return method.invoke(classWithMethods, params);
      aBoolean.set(true);
   }
   if ("methodA".equals(method.getName())) {
      return method.invoke(classWithMethods, params);
   }
 } 

}
```

Comment: An external orchestrator might be a good idea (or a bad idea, depending on context, and if I understand the hengxin correctly with an external orchestrator we must build a system so that the class where methodA and B reside can only be asked via the orchestrator). However, I think the question still remains, because you suggest a place *where* to do the magic, but the question is about *how* to do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really prevent that methodA or methodB is called (while other threads are inside the other method) but you can implement thread intercommunication in such a way so that you can still achieve what you want.

```
class MutualEx {
   boolean lock = false;

   public synchronized void methodA() {
      if (lock) {
         try {
            wait();
         }catch (InterruptedException e) {

         }
      }
      //do some processing
      lock = true;
      notifyAll();
   }

   public synchronized void methodB() {
      if (!lock) {
         try {
            wait();
         }catch (InterruptedException e) {

         }
      }

       //do some processing
      lock = false;
      notifyAll();
   }
}
```

Now, for this to work any Thread object you create should have a reference to the same instance of MutualEx object.

Comment: In this case threads there couldn't be more than 1 thread in methodA or methodB due to "synchronized" keyword.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the OPs question and he made many edits. Since interthread communication requires synchronized to be used, this is obviously not what he/she wants.

Comment: @dsp_user Thanks for your efforts. The discussions help me better understand and update my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms what you all need is `ENTER methodB only if no thread inside methodA`.

- Simply you can have a global counter, first initialized to 0 to record the number of threads that are currently inside `methodA()`. You should  have a `lock/mutex` assigned to protect the variable `count`.
- Threads entering methodsA do `count++`.
- Threads exiting methodA do `count--` .
- Threads that are entering methodB first should check whether `count == 0`.

  ```
  methodA(){
    mutex.lock();
    count++;
    mutex.signal();

    //do stuff   

    mutex.lock();
    count--;
    mutex.signal();     
  }

  methodB(){
    mutex.lock();
    if(count != 0){
        mutex.signal();
        return; 
    }
    mutex.signal();
    //do stuff    
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. However, does this disallow the situation (the 2nd situation) where multiple threads can enter `methodB` (and execute the application code) given that no threads are in `methodA`? Will the threads calling `methodB` have to wait on `mutex.lock()`?

Comment: No, it doesn't disallow enterring multiple threads to A. That mutex is only there for protecting 'count'. It only causes no 2 threads can access variable 'count' at the same time. :))

Answer (score 0):

You would need an int to count threads in methodA, and ReentrantLock.Condition to signal all threads waiting in methodB once there are no threads in methodA:

```
AtomicInteger threadsInMethodA = new AtomicInteger(0);
Lock threadsForMethodBLock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition signalWaitingThreadsForMethodB = threadsForMethodBLock.newCondition();

public void methodA() {
    threadsInMethodA.incrementAndGet();
    //do stuff
    if (threadsInMethodA.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        try {
            threadsForMethodBLock.lock();
            signalWaitingThreadsForMethodB.signalAll();
        } finally {
            threadsForMethodBLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public void methodB() {
    try {
        threadsForMethodBLock.lock();
        while (!Thread.isInterrupted() && threadsInMethodA.get() != 0) {
            try {
                signalWaitingThreadsForMethodB.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException("Not sure if you should continue doing stuff in case of interruption");
            }
        }
        signalWaitingThreadsForMethodB.signalAll();
    } finally {
        threadsForMethodBLock.unlock();
    }
    //do stuff

}
```

So each thread entering methodB will first check if nobody in methodA, and signal previous waiting threads. On the other hand, each thread entering methodA will increment counter to prevent new threads doing work in methodB, and on decrement it will release all the threads waiting to do stuff in methodB if no threads left inside methodA.